# MongoDB aggregate query to java code

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert mongoDB query to Javacode, but it is returning proper  values in mongo, but when running in java code it is not returning proper values for count (it is returning proper machineID, errorID but count as null, instead count should return number of records).

Mongo driver name

```
mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar
```

MongoDB query

```
 db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
    {"$match" : {"machineID": {"$in": ["1","10"]} , "errorID" : "error5"}},
    {"$group" : {_id : {machineID : "$machineID", errorID : "$errorID"}, count : {$sum  : 1} } },
    {$project : {machineID : "$_id.machineID", errorID : "$_id.errorID", count : "$count", _id : 0}}
])
```

Javacode:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> resultset =dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                new Document("$group", new Document("_id", new BasicDBObject("machineID", "$machineID").append("errorID","$errorID").append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum",1)))),
                new Document("$project", new Document("machineID", "$_id.machineID").append("errorID", "$_id.errorID").append("count", "$count").append("_id", 0))));
```

Returning values

```
machine ID -> 100
errorID  -> error3
count  -> null
```

Answer (score 3):

It helps if you try to keep the same sort of structure to see in JSON format examples:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> resultset =dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
  new Document("$match",
    new Document("machineID", new Document("$in", Arrays.asList("1","10")))
      .append("errorID", "error5")
  ),

  new Document("$group", 
    new Document("_id", 
      new Document("machineID", "$machineID").append("errorID","$errorID")
    ).append("count", new Document("$sum",1))
  ),

  new Document("$project", 
    new Document("machineID", "$_id.machineID")
      .append("errorID", "$_id.errorID")
      .append("count", "$count")
      .append("_id", 0)
  )
));
```